# Trouble with mustache-sharp multiplying empty lines

Tags: c#, mustache, text-rendering

I have this template in [mustache-sharp](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp):

```
Good Day,
{{#newline}}
The following asset has been retired by {{Actor}}:
{{#newline}}
{{AssetNumber}}: {{AssetDescription}}
Date retirement: {{DateRetired:dd.MM.yyyy}}
{{#newline}}
Comment: {{Comment}} 
{{#newline}}
{{#newline}}
Best Regards
{{#newline}}
Team Finances
{{#newline}}
{{#newline}}
Link: {{SystemUrl}}
```

When my ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API renders this into an e-mail, I get this output:

```
Good Day,
(nl1)
(nl2)
The following asset has been retired by Scheuner Marc (snm2):
(nl1)
(nl2)
1900007.0: HKB: Swisson sinus Dimmer
Date retirement: 31.05.2023 22:00:00
Comment: (some witty informational comment here)
(nl1)
(nl2)
(nl3)
(nl4)
Best Regards
(nl1)
(nl2)
Team Finances 
(nl1)
(nl2)
(nl3)
(nl4)
Link: https://investa-dev.bfh.ch
```

*(The `(nl#)` indicators are just to visualize how many newlines I get - those aren't really present in the output, just here to make my point clear)*

It appears as if rendering the mustache-sharp template duplicates each and every single `{{#newline}}` placeholder, and returns **two** empty/newlines for each placeholder.

Is there anything I can do to stop this? I'd really like the tool to render the template **as defined** - and not add extra empty lines at random ...

Comment: I'm curious to see what happens if you write `Good Day, {{#newline}}` without any enters or newline. It would be surprising if this even mattered but it is worth a try.

Comment: Now that I read more I see that in your example `{{#newline}}` is ignored in between `Date retirement:` and `Comment: {{Comment}}`. Is this really the case or did you forget to place the (nl) text yourself?

Comment: @Roe: thanks for the tip - but as you suspected - I don't see any difference in the resulting output, whether or not I put the `{{#newline}}` right behind the text, or on a separate line of its down. That's kinda the whole point in Mustache-sharp - you **explicitly** define the newlines with that placeholder - other newlines in the text template should not matter.

Comment: I completely agree, but since the code is ages old I thought that it could have been possible. Anyway I saw that there is a `HTMLSupport` class (I think your e-mail is HTML). It is supposed to remove most newlines if i understand the [github readme](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp#html-support) correctly.

Comment: @Roe: actually, I'm trying to do plain-text conversions - I want to avoid HTML for my e-mails if ever possible

Comment: Did you find a solution/workaround? I thought that it might be possible to create your own `newline` tag. This might give some insight on whether the problem lies in `String.Format` or in Mustache#